# How to get files from a commit, to a folder outside from my repository?

Tags: git, github

I need to get the files from 2 commits(of my choice) and put in 2 diferent folders outside my repository, i'll do a process, and than i need to be able to erase those 2 folders after.

I aready try some commands,`git -clone` doesn't work for me, i dont need the entire repository, just certain commits(one folder for each), and i have some inssues trying to erase the folder.

Other that i tried was `git archive`but the output didnt work for me. I need the files in the same way as the repository.

The one who went pretty close was `git --work-tree=<path> checkout <sha> -- .` but this command was stashing the files(who has diferences) on my repository, and i dont want that.

Is possible to do what i want, without making changes on my repository ?

Comment: What was wrong with `git archive`?  That just tars up the files in your repository.  There shouldn't be any difference.

Comment: Your last try did not stash, but overwrite, didn't it? Maybe you had stashed those changes before?

Comment: no, i clean the repository before trying this command, and the stash has no changes on the file, but shows like it do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git show <commit>:<file_path>     >    <path>`.

For example, `git show HEAD:foo/bar.c > ~/build/foo/bar.c`, `git show master:foo/bar.c > ~/backup/bar.c`.

`git show` can be replaced with `git cat-file -p` here.

If you want the whole repo, you could use `git worktree` if you have a newer version. It just checkouts a revision to another folder instead of the current work tree, so you don't have to make another clone.

For example, `git worktree add master ~/foo/`, which checkouts `master` into `~/foo/` while the current work tree stays unchanged.

Comment: thanks, work fine here, and make no changes on my worktree.

Answer (score 2):

From your repository directory which is called `project`:

```
mkdir ../foo && cd ../foo && echo 'gitdir: ../project/.git' >.git && git checkout <commit-ish> -- .
```

might produce the result you desire.